automorphism group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
When is the automorphism group of a group $G$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ?
I noticed that the only groups whose automorphism group is trivial are trivial one and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},$ and want to generalize the result.
I already found out that if $G$ is finite, only $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ satisfy the condition. As for infinite ones, I could prove that $G$ must be Abelian and its unique nontrivial automorphism is what changes each element into its inverse. I also found an example $G=\mathbb{Z}.$ Can someone prove that these are the only ones or find other examples?
